# $S_n$ is generated by elements of the form $(1k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that $S_n$ is generated by elements of the form $(1k)$.

I know that all elements in $S_n$ can be expressed as a multiplication of transpositions. I tried to take the direction of proving that every transposition can be written in the form of a product of elements of the form $(1k)$.

I started with a simple example of $(23)\in S_3$, but no matter what I tried I could not write it in the form of a multiplication of elements of the form $(1k)$. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: In general, $(1a)\sigma(1a)$ is the same "shape" as $\sigma$, but with the values of $1$ and $a$ swapped. So what is $(1a)(1b)(1a)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to remember that for a cycle $s= (s_1 \ s_2 \ \dots s_m)$ and a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, we have $$\sigma s \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(s_1) \ \sigma(s_2) \ \dots \sigma(s_m)).$$ You also know that $S_n$ is generated by the transpostions. So, we're reduced to the problem of writting any transposition $(a \ b)$ as a product of transpositions of the form $(1 \ k)$.

Based on that we get $$(a \ b) = (1 \ a) (1 \ b) (1 \ a).$$

As a follow up result, you can prove that the transpositions $(k \ k+1)$ generate $S_n$ by induction as $$(k \ k+1)= (1\ k+1)(1 \ k)(1 \ k+1).$$

Comment: Where can I find a proof for your first point?

Comment: It is quite easy to prove. Separate the two cases $x \notin \{\sigma(s_1), \dots, \sigma(s_m)\}$ and $x \in \{\sigma(s_1), \dots, \sigma(s_m)\}$. And prove that the image of $x$ under $\sigma s \sigma^{-1}$ is equal to the one of $(\sigma(s_1) \ \sigma(s_2) \ \dots \sigma(s_m))$ for both cases. Apart from that a bit of Google to find a prove on the web.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Note that $(23) = (12)(13)(12)$; likewise, any transposition can be written as a product of elements $(1, k)$, and $S_n$ is generated by its transpositions.